# SpringBoot RestAPI and CommandLine

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line

I am currently creating a RestApi project in SpringBoot.
We would like to add a program to this project that can be run from the command line.
Specifically, the image is that a monitoring batch on the server executes this program periodically.

I did some research on my own and thought it might be possible to implement this using CommandLineRunner.

I did some research on my own and thought it might be possible to implement this using CommandLineRunner.

```
@Component
public class DemoComponent implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

When I start springBoot, "Hello" is output to the console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1r7C.png)

What I would like is to run this process from the command line.
Please let me know.

Comment: I dont think its possible to do. In my understanding it will run at the time of startup

Comment: Is there any way to implement this other than CommandLineRunner?

Comment: May be you just expose as an API and access via command line using curl command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve here?

### Scheduler?

If you want to create a scheduled operation, you can utilize spring scheduler:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig {
    ...
}
```

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?")
public void scheduleHello() {

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    System.out.println("Hello - " + now);

}
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

---

### Monitoring??

If your purpose is to monitor your springboot service health, you might want to try `spring-actuator`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

you can monitor your service health in:
`/actuator/health` or `/health`

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators